# Minimum android API level for Google's ML Kit

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I'm working on an Andriod Studio project and I'm trying to use the Google ML Kit (Machine learning for mobile developers) API. I've been trying to figure out if I can use it since my target sdk is level 25-28, but I can't find the minimum required sdk level anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: what documentation you are referring? provide valid url in your question.

Comment: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/mlkitdemo-a0645/ml/apis

Comment: I found just for using ml kit with custom model requires android 16 or newer https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models

Comment: @KaranMer i have use "Natural Language" & "Vision" api

Answer (score 2):

Currently, as ML Kit is part of Firebase, `minSdk` **for ML Kit is 16**.
It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#mlkit-common_v19-0-0).

`minSdk 16` is valid for:

- ML Kit Common version 19.0.0
- ML Kit Vision version 20.0.0
- ML Kit Object Detection and Tracking Model version 16.0.0
- ML Kit Natural Language version 19.0.0
- ML Kit Language Identification Model version 19.0.0
- ML Kit Smart Reply Model version 19.0.0
- ML Kit Translate Model version 19.0.0
- ML Kit Model Interpreter version 19.0.0
- ML Kit Vision AutoML version 16.0.0

More information [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).